# Different icon for every feature in Feature Collection

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I have feature collection geojson. I want to set each of them different icon base to their attributes. But i could not find how. For now i just can set one image for just all layer. Is it possible to set each of feature different icon?

```
func drawPoint(geoJson : String , id: String) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(execute: {
        do {
            let data = geoJson.data(using: .utf8)
            let id = "kgm-\(id)"
            guard let shapeCollectionFeature = try MGLShape(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as? MGLShapeCollectionFeature else {
                fatalError("Could not cast to specified MGLShapeCollectionFeature")
            }

            let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: id, shape: shapeCollectionFeature, options: nil)
            self.mapView.style?.addSource(source)

            let pointLayer = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: id, source: source)
            let zoomStops = [
                13.49: NSExpression(forConstantValue: 0),
                13.5: NSExpression(forConstantValue: 1)
            ]

            pointLayer.iconOpacity = NSExpression(format: "mgl_interpolate:withCurveType:parameters:stops:($zoomLevel, 'linear', nil, %@)", zoomStops)
            pointLayer.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: id)
            pointLayer.iconAllowsOverlap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: true)
            self.mapView.style!.addLayer(pointLayer)
        } catch {
            print("GeoJSON parsing failed")
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to [set the image name](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/5.2.0/Classes/MGLStyle.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLStyle(im)setImage:forName:) in the style. This adds the specified image to the style's images.

If you would like to style to `iconImageName` based on the value for `id`, you may also want to try using `NSExpression(forKeyPath:)` rather than `NSExpression(forConstantValue:)`. For example:

`pointLayer.iconImageName = NSExpression(forKeyPath: id)`

Some examples that you may find helpful:

- [Clustering With Images](https://github.com/mapbox/ios-sdk-examples/blob/master/Examples/Swift/ClusteringWithImagesExample.swift#L45-L49)
- [Multiple Images in a Symbol Layer](https://github.com/mapbox/ios-sdk-examples/blob/master/Examples/Swift/MultipleImagesExample.swift#L22-L24)

Also, you may want to add the source and layer to the style on the main thread. Adding style layers on a background thread can result in unexpected behavior.